# Can't find soulution tkinter KeyError: 0

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
window = Tk ()
window.title(" ")
button = {}
name = -1
def click(number):
    button[number].config(bg="gray")
    print(number)
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(15):
        name = name + 1
        button[name] = Button(window, command=click(name), bg="white")
        button[name].config(height=2, width=4)
        button[name].grid(column = x, row = y)

window.mainloop()
```

I get error line 13, in module and line 8, in click. Not sure why this is happening, before I added the command=click(name) to Button it worked, but after I added it it stopped working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding in `command=click(name)` doesn't work as you are trying to assign `command` to the value returned from `click(name)` (you are accidentally running the function, which is then causing the `KeyError`).

Instead, try doing `command=lambda: click(name)`

Comment: Thank you it worked. Do you know how I could config the button clicked, cause right now it configs the 224'th button and not the button clicked

Comment: When clicking a button, the last value of `name` to be set will be used when calling `click(name)`, so you will notice that only the last button will be configured. To get around this, try doing `command=lambda id=name: click(id)`.